# Explain how the @service in Spring work

Tags: spring-boot, service

I following my teacher but i have some confused. This is a interface extends CrudRepository from Spring data

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
public interface TaskRepository extends CrudRepository<Task,Integer>{

}
```

and this is class Service use that interface:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TaskService {

private final TaskRepository taskRepository;

public TaskService(TaskRepository taskRepository) {
    this.taskRepository = taskRepository;
}


public List<Task> findAll(){

    List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Task task : taskRepository.findAll()) {
        tasks.add(task);
    }

    return tasks;
}
}
```

I confused that when an Controller want to use instance of TaskService. It just declare like this:

```
@Autowired
private TaskService taskService;
```

Who can explain me how it work? The init of TaskService have TaskRepository as argument. but I don't find any where init TaskRepository

Comment: Is it a Spring boot app? Do you have any configuration file/class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you mark your class with `@Component` or any variation of it such as `@Service`/`@Repository`/`@Controller`, you delegate it's object management to spring.

By doing

```
@Autowired
private TaskService taskService;
```

you are telling spring that, while creating an object of the controller, first create the object of TaskService and assign it to `taskService` variable declared in the controller.

Then spring will try to create object of `TaskService` but while creating, it sees the constructor

```
public TaskService(TaskRepository taskRepository) {
    this.taskRepository = taskRepository;
}
```

So, it will now try to create object of `TaskRepository` because without that, `TaskService` object can't be created.

Now, `TaskRepository` is an interface that extends `CrudRepository` and interfaces cannot be instantiated. Spring creates a proxy that implements `TaskRepository`, creates the object and injects it into `taskRepository` of the `TaskService` constructor.

So far, spring has built the `TaskRepository`, `TaskService` objects. It will simply inject `TaskService` object into autowired `taskService` variable of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

For your example you can omit the @Autowired for your constructor, because your Service has only one constructor.

JPA Repositoriy interfaces, TaskRepository will be automatically initialized by spring boot.

Comment: From `Spring Boot 1.5.7`, it is not required to annotate constructor with `@Autowire`

Comment: yes, if there is only one constructor, you can omit it.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot will automatically initialize JPA Repositoriy interfaces if found.

> By default, Spring Boot will enable JPA repository support and look in the package (and its subpackages) where @SpringBootApplication is located. If your configuration has JPA repository interface definitions located in a package not visible, you can point out alternate packages using @EnableJpaRepositories and its type-safe basePackageClasses=MyRepository.class parameter.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

In addition since Spring Framework 4.3 if there is a single constructor it will be attempted for autowiring.

https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/04/core-container-refinements-in-spring-framework-4-3

Comment: I got it. Thank you. My bad, i haven't learnt JPA yet. Just following my teacher . :P